# Windows Universal app with Android binding error

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I have created a simple universal app targeting Windows Phone 8.1 & Windows 8.1 in Visual Studio 2013. 
I added an android project and implemented MvvmLight.

ViewmodelLocator, viewmodels & messaging all work fine.
Databinding also works for the windows projects.

When I try adding databinding within the android project - at run time I get an error `Property not found: Text`

```
Button bindingButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

var vm = ViewModelLocator.Main;
this.AddBinding(() => vm.AsyncCompleted,
                () => bindingButton.Text,
                BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

OK - solved it myself.

I was originally following an example from the mvvm light home page which doesn't seem to work with an Android project within a Universal App.

The answer is to specify the Actual control to add the binding to and  pass the fully qualified View Model property to the binding:

```
        Button bindingButton  = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

        bindingButton.AddBinding(
                            () => ViewModelLocator.Main.AsyncCompleted,
                            () => bindingButton.Text,
                            BindingMode.OneWay);
```